# Möbius transformation given 1 $\rightarrow$ 1, -1 $\rightarrow$ i, -i $\rightarrow$ -1

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I'm struggling a bit with Möbius transformations. Im supposed to find a Möbius transformation that maps

1 $\rightarrow$ 1

-1 $\rightarrow$ i

-i $\rightarrow$ -1

I know that Möbius transformation has the form $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$

which gives me

$f(1)=\frac{a+b}{c+d}=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $a+b=c+d$

$f(-1)=\frac{-a+b}{-c+d}=i$ $\Rightarrow$ $-a+b=i(-c+d)$

$f(-i)=\frac{-ai+b}{-ci+d}=-1$ $\Rightarrow$ $-ai+b=ci-d$

From here i dont really know where to go.

I guess i can set $a=1$ since we got one free variable, and doing equationssystems, but that doesnt give me the right answer.

It gives me $f(z)=\frac{5z-5+2i}{(1-2i)z+3+4i}$

which does not map $1 \rightarrow 1$

Would anyone help me out to solve this in the best possible way?

Comment: Btw: I noticed that you got answers for several of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: Oh, i was not aware of that. Thanks!

Comment: After setting $a=1$ you have three _linear_ equations in three variables - what's the problem???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich There is no problem in solving Equation systems, the question is - is there any one way solving this that does not involve Equation systems?

Comment: I think the simple answer is "no", there is no way to solve this that does not involve equation systems. But beyond that, what I would suggest is that you take this opportunity to become more comfortable with equation systems; this one is actually quite simple, and you will certainly encounter problems whose solution depends on ever more complicated equation systems.

Comment: Okey, i understand. Ive tried doing the equation system, but that doesnt give me the correct answer... Would you mind help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, in a manner of speaking, a "simple" way that doesn't involve solving a system of equations (though of course it is just hiding that detail). I'll detail it simply because it's a neat standard tool to have in one's pocket: [cross ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio#Transformational_approach).

Here's the idea: given three complex numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, the unique Möbius transformation sending $\alpha \mapsto 1$, $\beta \mapsto 0$, and $\gamma \mapsto \infty$ is given by the cross ratio
$$S(z) = (z, \alpha; \beta, \gamma) := \frac{(z - \beta)(\alpha - \gamma)}{(z - \gamma)(\alpha - \beta)}.$$
(There is a fact hidden here, which is interesting to think about, namely that a Möbius transformation is uniquely determined by its values on any three points on the Riemann sphere.)

The point here is that if I know how to make a Möbius transformation $S$ sending $1 \mapsto 1$, $-1 \mapsto 0$, and $-i \mapsto \infty$, then I can also find one, call it $T$, sending $1 \mapsto 1$, $i \mapsto 0$, and $-1 \mapsto \infty$.
Then the *inverse* of $T$ sends $1 \mapsto 1$, $0 \mapsto i$, and $\infty \mapsto -1$, meaning that the composition
$$ T^{-1} \circ S $$
sends $1 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 1$, $-1 \mapsto 0 \mapsto i$, and $-i \mapsto \infty \mapsto -1$.

Now, inverses of Möbius transformations are not very hard to compute, but this is where the cute cross ratios come in: essentially what the above says is that the transformation we need is precisely
$$ (z, 1; -1, -i) = (w, 1; i, -1), $$
where we think of $z$ as the input and $w$ as the output.
Hence, setting the cross ratios up, we get
$$
\frac{(z + 1)(1 + i)}{(z + i)(1 + 1)} = \frac{(w - i)(1 + 1)}{(w + 1)(1 - i)}
$$
and what remains is to simplify this and rearrange it to have $w$ alone on one side.